# Drawing svg shapes on top of autodesk viewer, viewer's center coordinate moves when new versions of the same drawing are uploaded

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

We have a web application where we let the users draw SVG shapes on top of the Autodesk Viewer. We can translate the on-screen coordinates to the drawing using the worldToClient and the clientToWorld functions and it works beautifully, the shapes scale and move around with the drawing.

We also let the users update update the drawing by uploading new versions of it, and this has turned into a problem where the center coordinate (0,0) will change when the drawing has changed. That means that the SVG shapes will have the wrong positions when used with the new version of the drawing. It seems to me like somewhere in the translation the original positions of the .dwg files are ignored and a new center coordinate is computed from the content.

Our current workaround is for the users to draw a square frame around the drawings that they wish to use in this way. If all changes happen within that square the center will not move with new versions.

Does anyone have any thoughts, ideas, or experiences on how to solve this without the users needing to edit the drawings?

Comment: Does the aspect ratio of the sheets change, or just their size?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. An example: we have the original drawing of a top down blueprint of a building. We add a new room to the north and upload this new .dwg and use it instead. The geometry that was present in the original, was in the browser viewer at pos (A, B), but the same geometry will in the new version be at pos (C, D), even though that geometry was not moved in the file. It renders fine, but it throws off the positions of the svg layer which is positioned relative to the original geometry's positions.

Comment: Would you be able to provide two versions of such DWG file where the location of geometry moves though it was not touched on the sheet?
If you don't want to share it publicly you can email forge.help@autodesk.com

Comment: Thanks, I will find some simple examples and email them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `viewer.clientToWorld` and `viewer.worldToClient` with 2D drawings, the "world" typically means page dimensions. In your case, the two DXF files you provided had the same page dimensions, and the content in each DXF file was **scaled to fit the entire page**. That's why the "world" coordinates between the two DXF files didn't match.

Luckily, when converting DXF files, the Forge Model Derivative service also exports the "source to logical" transformation which I believe defines the conversion from the *original* coordinates to the *page* coordinates. When you compute the inverse of that transformation, you should be able to convert from *page* coordinates back to the *source* coordinates, and those are the ones you should store with your markups. The conversion into the *source* coordinates might look something like this:

```js
const res = viewer.clientToWorld(ev.clientX, ev.clientY);
if (res && res.point) {
    console.log('page coords', res.point);
    const sourceToLogicalXform = viewer.model.getData().metadata?.page_dimensions?.source_to_logical_xform;
    if (sourceToLogicalXform) {
        const sourceToLogical = new THREE.Matrix4().fromArray(sourceToLogicalXform).transpose();
        const logicalToSource = new THREE.Matrix4().getInverse(sourceToLogical);
        console.log('source coords', res.point.clone().applyMatrix4(logicalToSource));
    }
}
```